# Why a function is not calling by using v-on click in vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My code is

```
    var div = "<div class=\"liveContent\" id=\""+this.id+"\" refid=\""+refresh+"\" v-onclick=\"showWindow(this)\"><table><tr><td style=\"padding-left:10px;\"><b>"+this.animal+"</b><br>"+this.time+"<br>"+this.username+"</td></tr></table></div>";

$("#liveScroll").prepend(div);
```

And I have a function in methods as

```
 methods: {
  showWindow: function(e){
    alert(true);
  }
  },
```

When I click showWindow is not calling.

My html code is

```
<div id="liveScroll" class="liveScroll"></div>
```

Please help me to have a solution. Using this I am able to display the data but when I click on data nothing happens

Comment: It would be better to have your entire Vue file content

Comment: Updated   @Baskar

Answer (score 0):

```
var div = "<div class=\"liveContent\" id=\""+this.id+"\" refid=\""+refresh+"\" v-onclick=\"showWindow(this)\"><table><tr><td style=\"padding-left:10px;\"><b>"+this.animal+"</b><br>"+this.time+"<br>"+this.username+"</td></tr></table></div>";
```

Your above code have mistake :

it should not `v-onclick=\"showWindow(this)\"`

instead :

missing ( : ) colon after `v-on`

`v-on:click=\"showWindow(this)\"`

Comment: Sir nothing happens

Comment: same result nothing is happeing

Comment: I copied the code from google inspect element and put in the code, At that time it is working <div class="liveContent" id="5be7cfb2f46e932428eb2d0e" refid="1" v-on:click="showWindow(this)"><table><tbody><tr><td style="padding-left:10px;"><b>Rat</b><br><br>asdf</td></tr></tbody></table></div>

Comment: This is the code I copied at this time the function is calling. Otherwise nothing happening